# Trying to fit loaded numbers into a multi-dimensional (2D) array

Tags: java, arrays

This question is a bit logical, and I have no logic what so ever. I've tried everything so far.

Say there is an array of numbers which are:

```
[23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Since I'm programming a game, in a tiled based fashion. I am trying to fit it in a 2D array.

The width is 12 blocks wide, the height is 8 blocks wide. (Each  block 64px wide (NOT RELEVANT)).

So after every 12 numbers in the array of numbers above, I wish to have the program shift to the next row, producing results similar to:

```
long[][] mapData = new long[(int) width][(int) height];
mapData[0][0] = 23;
mapData[0][1] = 23
mapData[0][2] = 23
mapData[0][3] = 23
mapData[0][4] = 23
...
mapData[0][8] = 23
```

(Now the program figures out it has 8 as a width, so it moves to the next row)

```
mapData[1][0] = 23...
```

And it goes on until it does it all.

Comment: So, use loop+inner loop. What was your attempt?

Comment: use mapData[i][j] with above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
int array[]=[23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
long[][] mapData = new long[(int) width][(int) height];
int k = 0;
for(int i=0;i<width;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<height;++j){
        mapData[i][j]=array[k++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
long[][] mapData = new long[(int) width][(int) height];

for(int i=0; i < height; i++){
    for(int u=0; u < width; u++){
        mapData[i][u] = 23;
    }
}
```

Image the 2D-Array as a table. The program loops trough the first line of the table, filling each column of that line with '23'. After this line is finished, the outer for-loop counts i++, and so switches to the next line of the table. And so on, until each field has the value '23'. You can of course change the mapData[i][i] with any value you like.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that what you said and the code you provided don't match.

Usually, a matrix is read as `matrix[row][column]` so:

`matrix[0][n]` - `means first row column n`

`matrix[1][n]` - `means second row column n`

Anyway, in case you got them mixed and you use `matrix[0][n]` as `first column row n`, (in other words `matrix[column][row]`, then simply change my code to reflect exactly what you want.

What I undestood you want is :

```
Height of matrix is 12;
Width is 8
```

and not viceversa.

This should work:

```
private static final int[] array =
{ 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 26, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };

private static final int height = 12;
private static final int width = 8;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    int index = 0;
    //write on rows first then columns
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            result[row][col] = array[index];
            index++;
        }
    }

    //print the matrix
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            if (col < 7) {
                System.out.print(result[row][col] + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(result[row][col] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will print (12 rows, 8 columns):

```
23  23  23  23  23  23  23  23
23  23  23  23  31  31  31  31
31  31  31  31  31  31  31  31
26  4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   26  4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
26  4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   26  4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
26  4   4   4   4   4   4   4
4   4   4   4   26  4   4   4
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```

---

If you understand the matrix as `matrix[col][row]` and in fact want the output matrix to have `height = 8` and `width = 12` then make the following changes in my code:

```
private static final int height = 8;
private static final int width = 12;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    int index = 0;
    //write on columns first, then rows
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            result[i][j] = array[index];
            index++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (j < 11) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j] + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print(result[i][j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will print (8 rows, 12 columns):

```
23  23  31  26  4   4   26  4   4   26  4   4
23  23  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
23  23  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
23  23  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
23  31  31  4   26  4   4   26  4   4   26  4
23  31  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
23  31  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
23  31  31  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```